# How do you make simple_form timezone have values which are valid for postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, simple-form

In SimpleForm you can create a timezone input:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :time_zone, label: 'My time zone'
```

However the values which simple form puts into the form are not valid for Postgres:

```
<option value="American Samoa">(GMT-11:00) American Samoa</option>
<option value="International Date Line West">(GMT-11:00) International Date Line West</option>
<option value="Midway Island">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island</option>
<option value="Hawaii">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option value="Alaska">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
<option value="Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
<option value="Tijuana">(GMT-08:00) Tijuana</option>
...
```

The actual values need to correspond with the hash:

```
{"International Date Line West" => "Pacific/Midway", 
"Midway Island" => "Pacific/Midway", 
"American Samoa" => "Pacific/Pago_Pago", 
"Hawaii" => "Pacific/Honolulu", 
"Alaska" => "America/Juneau", 
"Pacific Time (US & Canada)" => "America/Los_Angeles", 
"Tijuana" => "America/Tijuana",
...}
```

How can you get the simple_form time_zone field to have the values in the correction "region/locality" format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails time zones are an oversimplification of the standard TZDB.  If you can avoid using them, I would use the full IANA TZDB zones instead.  In Ruby, this is easiest with the [TZInfo Gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/).

If you are stuck with them, then you can use the `MAPPING` constant from `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, as shown [in these docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).  That will let you correlate the Rails identifier back to the normal region/locality format.

See also the section at the bottom of the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) on Rails time zones.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you set these timezones to be the default in Rails? Is there any self-service solution to the form_for problem or do you just have to feed it a custom collection of data?

Comment: Actually, I'm afraid I'm a bit confused (also my brain's fried because it's late). The docs seem to be a bit scanty - how do you get those new timezones into the the form?

Comment: Since SimpleForm is a Rails thing, my guess is that you're stuck with Rails time zones.  (I could be wrong though, I don't work with Rails that often.)   So you'll want to just use the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.MAPPING` dictionary to resolve the full time zone id before you pass it through to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick:

```
f.input :time_zone, model: TZInfo::Timezone
```

but this will not render option names as you want, only values.